# Await inside of a file in Deno

Tags: async-await, deno

**EDIT**

*This is valid Deno code my code editor (VS code) was showing the error. Deno accepts this code.*

---

Hee everyone,

I am trying to await inside of a Deno file, but the following error is showing, 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function'. Since I am calling this command in the file itself not a specific method. There is nothing I can make 'async'

I have created a file called main.ts, the file looks something like this:

```js
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.3.1/mod.ts";
import db from "./db.ts";

const app = new Application();

await db.connect(); // The "'await' expression is only allowed within an async function" error is thrown here

app.start({ port: 5000 });
```

Anyone has an idea on how to do this properly?

Comment: Deno supports top-level await, has for a while now, how are you running it?

Comment: Is this a Deno error? Or an error thrown by your IDE, cause this is completely legal in Deno

Comment: @StevenGuerrero Yes you are right! This is Visual studio code giving an error not Deno . I have the Deno extension install weird that VS code still shows this error.

Ill edit the question!

Comment: @RogierdeRuijter Be sure to enable the extension for your workspace. You have to open the configuration extension and click the enable checkbox. It's a one time error, really

Comment: @StevenGuerrero Yeah I had to enable it! Now the error is one, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Whenever faced this you can just create an async function to contain all awaits, something like this will do:

```js
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.3.1/mod.ts";
import db from "./db.ts";

async function main() {
    const app = new Application();
    
    await db.connect();  //Now you're in an async function and await is valid
    
    app.start({ port: 5000 });
}

main();
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, however the issue the user OP is experiencing is not caused by bad syntax, but likely bad configuration in their development environment